# How do I see the concrete type that `some View` represents?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Say I have a view like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Title")
      HStack {
        if true {
          Text("Hello")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way to figure out the concrete type that `some View` represents (i.e. `VStack<TupleView<(Text, HStack<Optional<Text>>)>>`)?

Right now my workaround is to copy the code to a Playground, get it to compile, and then print:

```
print(type(of: MyView().body))
```

However, this is very tedious especially if `MyView` has a lot of properties.

Is there a simpler way to see the opaque type of `some View` (E.g. similar to how you can option-click an implicitly typed variable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `some View` to `String`. An error message will appear:

> Cannot convert return expression of type `VStack<TupleView<(Text, HStack<Text?>)>>` to return type `String`

So now you know what type it is. It's a `VStack<TupleView<(Text, HStack<Text?>)>>`.